# cassandra cluster, 1 table, how to plan forward

Tags: cassandra

I am planning to create an application that will use just 1 cassandra table. Replication factor will be probably 2 or 3. I might start initially with 2 cassandra server and then keep adding servers as needed. But I am not sure if I need to pre-plan anything so that the table is distributed uniformly when I add more servers. Are there any best practices or things I need to be aware? I read about tokens , http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/initialize/token_generation , but I am not sure what I need to do.

I suppose the keys have to be distrubuted uniformly in the cluster, so:

1. how will that happen i.e. when I add the 2nd server and say the 1st one already has 1 million keys
2. do I need to pre-plan the keyspace or tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest two things.

First, when designing your schema, pick a good partition key (1st column in the primary key).  You need to ensure a couple of things:

1. There are enough values such that you can distribute it to an arbitrary amount of nodes.  For example, sex would be a bad partition key, because you only have two values and therefore can only distribute it to two nodes.
2. The distribution across different partition key values is more or less uniform.  For example, country might not be best, because you will most likely have most of your rows in just a few unique countries.

Secondly, to ease deployment of new nodes later consider setting up your cluster to use virtual nodes (vnodes).  If you do that you will be able to skip a few steps when expanding your cluster.

To configure virtual nodes, set `num_tokens` in `cassandra.yaml` to more than 1.  This will decide how many virtual nodes your node will have.  A recommended value is 256.

Later, when you add new nodes, you need to make sure `add_bootstrap` is true in `cassandra.yaml` for your new nodes.  Then you configure network parameters as usual to match your cluster, and finally start your node.  It should automatically bootstrap and start streaming appropriate data.  After everything is settled down, you can run cleanup (`nodetool clean`) on your other nodes to make sure they purge redundant data that they're no longer responsible for.

For more detailed documentation, please see  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_add_node_to_cluster_t.html

Comment: thanks. My key will probably be a long, so I suppose it is good enough